# How to set video memory with KVM/QEMU virtualization?

Tags: kvm, qemu

As a long-time VirtualBox user I'm used to being able to set video memory available to my virtual machines, but unfortunately I cannot seem to find such an option for when I start KVM/QEMU VMs with:

```
qemu-kvm -boot d OS.img
```

I know how to set RAM available, however, with the `-m RAM` option, which I'm mentioning in the hope that people won't confuse what I'm asking about with RAM. Here's a screenshot showing how I set this option in VirtualBox VM settings:

[image]

Comment: Why aren't you using virt-manager?

Comment: Not a bad question. Part of it is because the installation location is /var/lib/libvirt/images, which doesn't have enough space left for it to store my Win10 VM. Another reason is because I like to create desktop launchers for my VMs, which I know how to do when he VM is started from the command-line, not so sure if it's started using virt-manager.

Comment: You don't have to store disk images there. It's just the default location. You can store them anywhere else you want. Just choose a new location or even create a new storage pool.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected I might be wrong on that one.

Answer (score 6):

The video memory size can be defined using the `vgamem_mb` property on the VGA device:

```
qemu -device VGA,vgamem_mb=64 ...
```

will allocate 64 MiB to the framebuffer (instead of the default 16 MiB IIRC).

Some drivers have specific properties:

- the virtio GPU uses `max_hostmem` instead to specify how much host memory it’s allowed to use;
- the QXL driver adds `ram_size_mb`, `vram_size_mb`, and `vram64_size_mb`, to define the size of the two regions it uses: `ram` stores the framebuffer, command rings, rendering commands and image data, and `vram` stores spice surfaces (see [this email](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2012-06/msg01898.html) for details).

Comment: Thanks, one side question. Which driver would be best for a Windows 10 VM?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry...

Comment: I tried this with a Windows 10 VM and it's still saying there's only 32 MB video memory available to it, even though I allocated 128 MB and there's no error at the command-line.

Comment: What driver are you using?

Comment: I used the above `-device` specification, although I combined it with the `qemu-kvm` command I was using, namely: `qemu-kvm -boot d /data/VMs/win10.img -m 8192 -smp 3 -soundhw hda -device VGA,vgamem_mb=128`. There's an error mentioned relating to the audio (`audio: Unknown audio driver `pa'`), but as that's not graphics related I didn't think it counted.

Comment: OK, and what version of QEMU are you using?

Comment: QEMU: 2.12.0. Kernel: 4.17.13. OS: openSUSE Tumbleweed.

Comment: Right, so it should work; perhaps Windows 10 only uses 32 MiB on a VESA device (which is the default in QEMU 2.2 and later). In the QEMU console, `info ramblock` will show the amounts of memory allocated to the various memory blocks, including video memory; for me it correctly reflects the `vgamem_mb` property. If you install VMware Tools in Windows you could try `-vga vmware` instead.

Comment: For me `info ramblock` returns: `info: No menu item 'ramblock' in node '(dir)Top'`.

Comment: Not on the command line, in the QEMU console (connect to QEMU, then Ctrl-Alt-2).

Comment: Where do I get VMWare Tools? I DuckDuckGo searched it and found its docs and they only mentioned if I started Windows in VMWare, not in QEMU. No download link given, only how to get it from within VMWare itself.

Comment: See [here](https://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/6.7latest/windows/index.html).

Comment: I tried installing it but it said I needed to run it in a VM. Apparently it doesn't recognize KVM/QEMU as a valid means of virtualization.

Comment: Looking at the contents of the VMware Tools ISO, it looks like it doesn’t install a graphics driver anyway — it might be worth trying Windows as-is with `-vga vmware`, perhaps the driver is built-in nowadays. (I’m following the QEMU documentation and source code; I don’t have a Windows VM to test with. Linux VMs report the correct amount of video memory with `-vga std` and `-vga vmware`.)