# Cannot allocate video mem to "virtio-vga-gl" VGA in Qemu

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, mesa

I want to allocate some video memory to a Qemu VM which uses `virgl` VGA to enable 3D acceleration. I typed this command to try to allocate 1G video memory to it:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda RedHat.qcow2 -m 2G -smp 8 \
    -device virtio-vga-gl,max_hostmem=1000 -display gtk,gl=on
```

But it doesn't work; the `virgl` device in VM does not obtain the allocated video memory. This can be shown by `info ramblock` command in Qemu monitor:

```
(qemu) info ramblock
              Block Name    PSize              Offset               Used              Total
   0000:00:03.0/vga.vram    4 KiB  0x00000000800c0000 0x0000000000800000 0x0000000000800000
0000:00:03.0/virtio-vga.rom    4 KiB  0x00000000808c0000 0x0000000000010000 0x0000000000010000
```

, or `glxinfo -B` command in guest OS:
[image]

So, how can I allocate video memory to `virtio-vga-gl` device? The host is Ubuntu 20.10, the guest is RHEL 8.5, and Qemu is built from latest source 6.2.0-rc4.

As a side question, where can I find full documents of latest Qemu options and its properties like `max_hostmem=1G` or `show-cursor=on`? I know `-device help` command line option of Qemu, but it contains no further document. I googled a lot but can only find docs like [this](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation) which almost says nothing. [This document](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/qemu-system-x86/qemu-system-x86_64.1.en.html) is too old. I also read [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463008/how-to-set-video-memory-with-kvm-qemu-virtualization). It's only 3 years old, but already out-of-date. I'll appreciate it if you can let me know the url in comment.